# How to reject messages after shoveling from one queue to another?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, dead-letter, rabbitmq-shovel

With Spring and RabbitMQ I set up two topic-exchanges `x`and `dlx` and two queues `q`and `dlq`. `q` is bound to `x` and `dlq` to `dlx`. `dlx` is configured as dead-letter-exchange for `q`.

When a message in `q` is rejected (with unqueue) it is successfully send to `dlx` and then to `dlq`.

Now I use the shovel-plugin to move dead-lettered messages in `dlq` back to `q`. This works successfully as long as the messages are processed successfully this time (ack).

But if one of these shovelled messages in`q` is rejected again it is dropped silently. I expect it to be send to the DLX `dlx` again. Did I configure something wrong or did I misunderstood the concept of DLX or shovels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are hitting a flavor of this...

> It is possible to form a cycle of message dead-lettering. For instance, this can happen when a queue dead-letters messages to the default exchange without specifiying a dead-letter routing key. Messages in such cycles (i.e. messages that reach the same queue twice) will be dropped if there was no rejections in the entire cycle.

...because you're shoveling. See [Dead Letter Exchanges](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html).

Instead, configure the DLQ with TTL, and dead-letter configuration that causes expired messages to be routed back to the original queue. That way, the `x-death` header gets two entries - 1 for the rejections from the original queue and 1 for the expiry from the DLQ.

I am guessing that, with shoveling, the broker thinks there is a cycle.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I read the quote before but am am not sure if it applies here. It states `if there was no rejections in the entire cycle`. In my case the message is rejected once.
I will try to use a special dead-letter routing key. Let's see what happens then...

Comment: Yeah - I was just speculating - however, I have successfully used the TTL technique many times.

Comment: I could solve it using a dead-letter routing key `x-dead-letter-routing-key`. (TTL is no solution for my use case.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is cycles. Assuming you are using the shovel plugin from the Rabbit management GUI, this changes the routing key for the message to explicitly use the routing key of the queue on the 'Default Exchange'

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#exchange-default

> The default exchange is a direct exchange with no name (empty string) pre-declared by the broker. It has one special property that makes it very useful for simple applications: every queue that is created is automatically bound to it with a routing key which is the same as the queue name.

Based on your example above, I assume you have these settings:

- `q` arguments - `x-dead-letter-exchange = dlx`
- `q` binding: `test_message`
- `dlq` binding: `test_message`

So, if you send a message to `x` with a routing key of `test_message`, this is how it's routed:

1. Appears in `q`
2. Consumer in `q` gets message, sends nack, which sends to `dlx` with routing key `test_message`
3. `dlx` has the `dlq` configured to bind to `test_message` routing key, so message appears in `dlq`

Now, when you use the shovel plugin from `dlq` to move all messages into `q` like this:

[image]

Then this sends a message to `exchange = ''` and `routing_key = 'q'`. Also from https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html#using-optional-queue-arguments it states:

> If this is not set, the message's own routing keys will be used.

So now this is what happens:

1. Message appears in `q` with `routing_key = q`
2. Since there is no `x-dead-letter-routing-key` configured, it dead letters to `dlx` with routing_key `q`
3. No binding to q in `dlx`, message dropped

2 potential fixes:

1. Add another binding to `dlq` to `routing_key = q`
2. Manually configure the `x-dead-letter-routing-key` on the `q` queue to always send to the same routing key on dead-letter